# SQAlchemy>2.0 does not INSERT or UPSERT into MySQL when using text() function

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

We have recently updated to `SQLAlchemy==2.0.23` which requires the usage of [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) to format executed queries.

In older versions e. g. `SQLAlchemy==1.4.49` we could `INSERT` or `UPSERT` data using `session.execute(my_query)` which does not work anymore with `SQLAlchemy==2.0.23` using `session.execute(text(my_query))`.

Here's a minimal example of the problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session


my_query = """
    INSERT INTO test (`col_a`, `col_b`)
    VALUES (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9) as nd
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE `col_a` = nd.`col_a`, `col_b` = nd.`col_b`
"""

constring = "mysql+pymysql://my_user:my_password@my.host:3306/my_db"
connection = create_engine(constring)
connection.echo = True # enable logging
session = create_session(bind=connection)
cursor = session.execute(text(my_query))  # does not INSERT or UPSERT
```

Interestingly, if I run the plain query on the database, it works perfectly and the logging also shows a working query.

Any hints on how to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you called `session.commit()`?

Comment: To expand on the above comment: I don't think `session.execute` has ever committed, at least in the 1.x releases. Perhaps your previous code used a session configured with `autocommit=True`? Or perhaps it used `engine.execute`, which used to autocommit until 2.0.

Comment: Calling `session.commit()` was actually the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if newer versions of SQLAlchemy `>2` do not apply an auto commit.

Log for `sqlalchemy==2.0.23`:

```
2023-11-16 07:34:26,461 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2023-11-16 07:34:26,461 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2023-11-16 07:34:26,525 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@sql_mode
2023-11-16 07:34:26,525 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2023-11-16 07:34:26,555 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
2023-11-16 07:34:26,556 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2023-11-16 07:34:26,618 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-11-16 07:34:26,619 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
    INSERT INTO test (`col_a`, `col_b`)
    VALUES (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9) as nd
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE `col_a` = nd.`col_a`, `col_b` = nd.`col_b`
2023-11-16 07:34:26,619 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00026s] {}
```

Same log for `sqlalchemy==1.4.49`:

```
2023-11-16 07:35:25,120 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2023-11-16 07:35:25,120 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2023-11-16 07:35:25,182 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@sql_mode
2023-11-16 07:35:25,182 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2023-11-16 07:35:25,215 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
2023-11-16 07:35:25,215 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2023-11-16 07:35:25,279 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
    INSERT INTO test (`col_a`, `col_b`)
    VALUES (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9) as nd
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE `col_a` = nd.`col_a`, `col_b` = nd.`col_b` 
2023-11-16 07:35:25,279 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00036s] {}
2023-11-16 07:35:25,310 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Thanks to @snakecharmerb for pointing me in the right direction!